# What should I do with UnicodeEncodeError:

Tags: python, unicode, decode, encode

It looks like that there are many of these `UnicodeEncodeError` errors, but none of them were useful for me.

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 86, in <module>

  File "...", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf8' in position 255: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is your **full** traceback? What are you printing *to* (an IDE console? A terminal? Windows console? A pipe?)

Comment: Notice that the error is a **encode** error, so it is not the *decode* that throws it, not directly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters a `decode` will do an implicit `encode` first if the string isn't unicode; it would fit the symptoms.

Comment: @MarkRansom: yes, that's why I qualified my comment as *not directly*.

Comment: what I'm printing to? What u mean with that?
I've been stucked at this problem for a while (4-hours), and it still doesn't work.
what should I do?

Comment: Just to be clear: without showing us what is in `new_text` and the full traceback, your question is unanswerable. Either there is existing Unicode data in `new_text`, or you are using a console or terminal or pipe where the environment states it is using ASCII or there is no way to determine the environment codec. The full traceback starts with the text `Traceback (most recent call last):`. Showing the contents of `new_text` is best done with `print repr(new_text)`.

Comment: @py.codan: right, you are trying to decode already-decoded Unicode values. I'd love to see what `new_text` actually contains, but I gave you a best-guess answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have data that is *already decoded* in `new_text`. You either have a mix of unicode and byte string data, or you have only unicode values.

What happens is that you ask Python to *decode* already decoded data, a `unicode` object. To make this work, Python will first *encode to bytes*, using the default ASCII encoding. That fails for those objects.

Either don't decode (if all your data is already decoded to `unicode` objects), or differentiate between objects that need to be decoded vs. those that are already `unicode`:

```
[x.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in new_text]
```

Comment: This doesn't give an Error, but it stille not gives me the new_text in the searched letters.  
This is the text I get:
`ik \nan gkvfscdsennrr\n  ip vainsateeyai u\xe5 l rmne  vpb 0te\xe6totaktlaks s enns/ndn verseeaen\xe6o1mirglst .diofe Mnsoas ,esfs btelue vlrafsttsefne2kted ok e.n v.fnl,dkky k) entet Imdssk rsedfrg\ngt thgee\n- oKmraeo\n g l  e  tpsTrs a\nememv \ndtkg\xe5,nrn t pim\xf8mrgr pk\xe6 arenea r iryiksdrlh\xe6 m.`

Comment: @py.codan: I'm not sure what you are asking here. Are you wondering why the data printed is using escape sequences? If so see [Python ascii utf unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27256421) and print individual elements (`print new_text[0]`) or produce one unicode object (print `u' '.join(new_text)`).

Comment: @py.codan: take into account that printing Unicode data to a console that doesn't support your codepoints can lead to more encoding errors. Windows consose especially is sensitive to this.

Comment: I want a random text, with letters that a get from `input`.
In this text I want 55 letters, and this letters should include æø. It should not give any sence (the new_text), but it should include these letters I showed. The text itself is't wrong, it have the "right" structure, but it should be unicoded (I think).

Comment: print u' '.join(new_text) HELPED ME !
THANKS A LOT @Martijn Pieters!